# System.Data.Sqlite + EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to get the System.Data.Sqlite (1.0.92.0) work with EF6 (6.0.2) but i cannot get this working. I installed designer components for VS2013 and installed latest nuget packages of the Sqlite which also contains System.Data.Sqlite.EF6.dll assembly. I even tried adding EntityFramework assemblies to GAC. But nothing worked, I always end up with the following dialog in VS2013.

[image: EF6+Sqlite Database First VS2013]

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. It works fine with EF5 but don't work with ef6.1.1. I installed sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.93.0.exe that add data source and I was able to made connection string. Then I installed System.Data.SQLite EF6 and tried create ado.net data model but got the same error.